# What is the fastest way to calculate nearby points from large data set of points

Tags: java, geometry, java-3d

I have a large set of 3d points, (20,000+), scattered throughout a 3d space. I need to identify which points are within a specific arbitrary range of each point in the set. For example, for each point, what is the group of points that is within a range of 10 units. The permutations for this are pretty big. So, what would be the most computationally efficient way to approach this ? (I need to solve this using java only.)

Comment: It seems like you could reduce the search space by ordering the points and using a sliding cubic window, say of side length 20. This seems like it would let you rapidly eliminate points from comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), which is basically a k-dimensional binary tree. Range search in k-d tree is very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a theorical question without code, I will throw my 2 cents here. If you don't use any geometrical DB like postgis (http://postgis.net/), I will suggest the following with the premise that the points have three coordinates (X, Y, Z).

Make three Arrays containing the id of the point and one of the coordinates. Sort them by coordinates. Then for each points, check if the last and the next are within range. If the two are not, eliminate that point. Make that for each array. You will then have a much less space to compute. Then for each points within the reach of a point, calculate the distance and flag, eliminate the fartest points.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a space filling curve and approximate. Treat the points as a binary and interleave it. Then sort the numbers and exploit that the curve visits nearby points first. You can try many curves most likely it depends on the points.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). Or maybe a range tree like a kd-tree, it will return all points in a box, and then you just filter all at the desired distance from your query point.

Comment: This is an intersting idea, a step approach... +1

Answer (score 0):

Using an ArrayList that is preallocated to full size. (Uses a cube shape zone)

```
public class Point3D {
    public int x, y, z;

    public static List<Point3D> allWithinRange(List<Point3D> possiblePoints, int x, int y, int z, int inter) {
        List<Point3D> list = new ArrayList<Point3D>(possiblePoints.size());
        possiblePoints.stream()
                .filter(it -> it.x <= x + inter && it.x >= x - inter)
                .filter(it -> it.y <= y + inter && it.y >= y - inter)
                .filter(it -> it.z <= z + inter && it.z >= z - inter)
                .forEach(list::add);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use a sphere instead of a cube then you will have to filter them (I recommend after the other filters because it will be a sub category) by using that algorithm.